# Getting process main entry C#

Tags: c#, memory, handle, readprocessmemory

I'm currently making a memory scanner using C#.
Therefore I want to determine the process' main memory entry point (often `0x400000` for `x32`).
I have already opened a `pHandle` with all acces.
How do I get the start address to scan?

Comment: I have tried to determine wheter the process is x32 or x64. By doing that I can use the default entry.

Comment: Check this out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule.entrypointaddress(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: Processes don't have base addresses, modules do

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[ProcessModule.EntryPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule.entrypointaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
// Get the main module associated with 'myProcess'.
myProcessModule = myProcess.MainModule;
IntPtr MainEntry = myProcessModule.EntryPointAddress;
```